# How do i add todays value in current week?

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

I'm using this code to print 1 week, but it is excluding today's value:

```
DATE(post_date) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

query:

```
SELECT sum($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value)
FROM $wpdb->posts
INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
    ON $wpdb->posts.id = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
WHERE post_status = 'publish' && post_type = 'alj_cases' 
&& DATE(post_date) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY meta_key
LIKE '%negative%'
ORDER BY post_date
```

Comment: Can you please share your whole query, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: @Mureinik whole query added

Comment: I doubt that query works

Comment: well it is working...

Comment: Leave out all the PHP stuff for now. Instead, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is get posts from the last week, you could use `date_diff` to check that the difference between the post date and the current date is no more than seven days:

```
SELECT     SUM($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value)
FROM       $wpdb->posts
INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
        ON $wpdb->posts.id = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
WHERE      post_status = 'publish' AND
           post_type = 'alj_cases' AND
           DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), post_date) <= 7 AND
           meta_key LIKE '%negative%'
```